# 'TypeError: 'list' object is not callable' when using reversed

Tags: python, python-2.7

I really cannot find error. Could you help?

```
import re
while True:
    a = raw_input() #unos

    # stepenovanje
    list = re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[\^]\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+', a) #odvajamo stepene
    for elem in list:
        powers = elem.split("^")
        powers = list(reversed(powers)) #obrtanje liste
        print powers, 'pow'
        result = float(powers[1]) ** float(powers(0))
        powers = powers.remove[0]
        powers = powers.remove[0]
        while len(powers) > 1:
            result = result ** float(powers[0])
            powers = powers.remove[0]
        result = result ** float(powers[0])
        a = a.replace(list[list.index(elem)], str(result)) #smestanje rezultata na mesto cinilaca u stringu a
        print a, 'posle stepenovanja'
```

the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dusan/PycharmProjects/untitled1/2.py", line 10, in <module>
    powers = list(reversed(powers)) #obrtanje liste
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

You assigned the result of `re.findall()` to the name `list`:

```
list = re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[\^]\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+', a) #odvajamo stepene
```

Don't do that. That's now a list *instance* instead of the `list` *type*. Rename that variable:

```
degrees = re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[\^]\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+', a)
for elem in degrees:
```

I'm also not sure why you use `list[list.index(elem)]` when you could just use `elem` *directly*.

Comment: I renamed it, but there's still a problem :(

Comment: @DusanMilosevic: 'a problem' doesn't tell me anything. Are you doing this in the interactive session? If so you need to delete the old binding with `del list` to un-mask the global built-in. Or restart your Python session.

Comment: Always give us the full error message; you implied you had the exact same error while what you posted is a different error (different line).

Comment: I think i had the same message, i can't remember. I thought i had the same message.

Comment: Same exception, different line in the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

I found an error. In `result = float(powers[1]) ** float(powers(0))` i used () instead of []. Thanks!